# access user control stackpanel from main window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

i have a user control which defined like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LearnWPF1.DesignerPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel     
              PreviewMouseDown="panel_PreviewMouseDown"          
              x:Name="panel"
              Orientation="Vertical" 
              Background="White"
              AllowDrop="True"
              DragOver="panel_DragOver"
              Drop="panel_Drop"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

now i want my main window to have access on the stackpanel, how can i do that?
currently my main window get the user control reference like this:

```
<local:DesignerPanel x:Name="DesignerPanel"></local:DesignerPanel>
```

the problem now is the PreviewMouseDown event only works on UserControl's code behind, if i do that on MainWindow, it wont works.

Answer (score 0):

`XAML` in the `MainWindow`:

```
<local:DesignerPanel x:Name="DesignerPanel" 
                     PreviewMouseDown="DesignerPanel_OnPreviewMouseDown"/>
```

`Code-behind` in the `MainWindow.cs`

```
private void DesignerPanel_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Another way is add the event handle in code-behind that can listen the handle event. `DesignerPanel.AddHandle(UIElment.PreviewMouseDown,DesignerPanel_OnPreviewMouseDown)`

Answer (score 0):

You could access the `StackPanel` from the `MainWindow` like this:

```
StackPanel panel = DesignerPanel.panel;
```